# I want to change button background color dynamically in based on collection using Wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

Student:

```
public class Student
{
    private int _studentNo;
    public int StudentNo
    {
        get { return _studentNo; }
        set { _studentNo = value; }
    }

    private Rank _state;
    public Rank State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set { _state = value; }
    }
}
```

Rank:

```
public enum Rank
{
    Pass,
    Fail
}
```

RankBoard:

```
public class RankBoard
{

    private static ObservableCollection<Student> _studentList;
    public static ObservableCollection<Student> StudentList
    {
        get { return _studentList; }
        set { _studentList = value; }
    }

    public RankBoard()
    {

        LoadDetails();
    }

    private void LoadDetails()
    {
        StudentList = new ObservableCollection<Student>()
        {
            new Student()
            {
                StudentNo=1,
                State=Rank.Pass
            },
            new Student()
            {
                StudentNo=2,
                State=Rank.Fail
            },
            new Student()
            {
                StudentNo=3,
                State=Rank.Pass
            },
        };
    }
}
```

BackgroundChangedConvertor:

```
public class BackgroundChange : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var b = value as Button;
        if(b!=null)
        {
            foreach (var x in RankBoard.StudentList)
            {
                if ((System.Convert.ToInt32(b.Content)==x.StudentNo)&&((x.State.ToString()=="Pass")))
                {
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
   <Window x:Class="ButtonColorChanged.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonColorChanged"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:BackgroundChange x:Key="Color"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="1" Width="75" Height="25" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Color}}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn2" Content="2" Width="75" Height="25" Margin="0 20 0 20" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Color}}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn3" Content="3" Width="75" Height="25" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Color}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I tried to change button background color depends upon to State(Pass or Fail) in Collection. but i Run this progrom object value throw null value in BackgroundChange class. so Button background color doesn't affect.? How do i do it.?

Answer (score 1):

`StudentList` property of `RankBoard` is `static`, and you are initializing in non-static constructor.

So, create a `static constructor` and do initialization there.

```
static RankBoard()
{
    LoadDetails();
}

private static void LoadDetails()
{ ... }
```

Secondly, you can't do `var b = value as Button;` , the `value` parameter would contain the bounded value in your `Button's` binding. `value` won't give you the `sender` as in an event handler.

Comment: I do that but value throw null in backgroundchange class.

Comment: @Divagar replace last line of `Convert` method :  `return null;` with `return Brushes.Yellow` and tell what happens.

Comment: Thanks AnjumSKhan. Button color changed in red, I have two problem 1). value throw null 2). i put static method,and static constructor but error will be display " access modifiers not allowed on static constructors "

Comment: @Divagar Remove `public` from `static constructor`. And change `LoadDetails()` method to `static`.

Comment: AnjumSKhan Thanks for your help, Successfully Color Changed. because i did't pass element name so value is throw null, now i do that it's worked.

Comment: @Divagar I have already updated my answer and you can mark it as correct one.